# How to properly show progress of async tasks used by Google Room

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin, progress

I'm using Google Room to implement persistence of data in my Android app (Kotlin code). Room demands all the operations (queries to and from the database) to be async. I would like the user to wait for the operation to execute, preventing him from interacting with components that would not be configured properly before the end of the query. How can I achieve this, since I can't access the UI thread from a async task?

PS: I also do some calls to an API where the progress/loading indicator would be nice to have. I'm using RxJava in those calls, but I'm fairly new to this technology, and I'm not sure how to properly structure it.

Sample of a db operation:

```
private fun getDataFromCache() {
  //show progress indicator here
        execute({
            try {
                //Get items from cache
                val entities = daoData.findAll()

                if (entities.isNotEmpty()) {
                    //do something
                } else {
                    //do something else
                }
            }
            catch (e: Exception){
                Log.e("error", e.toString())
            }
            finally{
                //dismiss progress indicator here
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To prevent the user from using the app while the fetch is working you can use a library like [KProgressHUD](https://github.com/Kaopiz/KProgressHUD) to display a modal, user interface blocking HUD, which can optionally include a progress indicator. You only need to replace the `show progress indicator here` comment with the modal HUD creation and `//dismiss progress indicator here` with removal of the HUD on the UI thread.

With regards to progress, you have to manually update the HUD progress inside your `execute` code. First you need to split your dao `findAll()` call into one that returns the number of elements you have in total (some `SELECT COUNT(*)` query) to know how long the total progress bar might be. Then, instead of `findAll()` you would need to create batched/paged calls to the database, fetching N records in a loop. Inside this loop you can then update the HUD with the percentage of your current loop progress vs the total count you got before starting.

I'm not familiar with the Room API, so I can't provide any pseudo code on such a loop, but usually it all boils down to opening an SQL cursor and keep fetching batches of data in a loop until it is exhausted, keeping track of how many have items have you read and accumulating them in a list.

Comment: Cheers mate, we've followed a similar approach!